# Base64String value doesn't display in android browsers

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I just want to ask if there is a workaround for displaying the Base64String to a textarea or paragraph, I tried displaying it on a paragraph on click but it didn't work, it just displays a blank message but the value is not null.

This only happens on Android Phone Browsers. I'm using qrcode.s library and for downloading the image I use C# and javascript to send the data, it works fine on my pc but it doesn't work on any Android Phone Browsers.

I can't show you my C# code but I can show my javascript code:

HTML:

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<button id="testClick">Test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
        width: 256,
        height: 256,
        colorDark : "#000000",
        colorLight : "#ffffff",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
    qrcode.makeCode("KAJFAK23");

    //Get the src from the img tag injected by the qrcode library
    const test = document.getElementById("qrcode");
    const child = test.getElementsByTagName("img");

    const clickTest = document.getElementById("testClick");


    clickTest.addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(child[0].src) //getting the base64string value from the img tag
    })        
</script>
```

Actually this is just a code from my main project, I'm testing it so I can find some workaround or  a fix.

Comment: what is the name of the QR code library that you are using ? can you please provide link of library?

Comment: https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ here's the link

Comment: ok thanks. Your code works fine on a normal desktop browser. What error do you get in the Android mobile browser? Also are you using `WebView` or Chrome for Android ?

Comment: There's no error actually, the problem is that the base64String value doesn't shows up on any element tag like paragraph or textarea for android phone browsers, but when I tried using an Iphone it works fine, I think it's a problem with the android app, so i'm looking for a workaround for this issue or maybe use a different library instead.

Comment: there is an Open issue for the same mentioned over here https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/issues/287

Comment: It seems there is still a minor issue with it maybe will find a much more reliable library. The problem was the regex in the library. Thank you somuch!